# Disable Android + Mobile browser scrolling, rotating scaling wierdness

Tags: javascript, android, touch

I'm making a custom livecoding/visual performance system. I'm to using HTML on phones and tablets to generate inputs like faders (sliders), and potentiometers (knobs). Thing is mobile browsers are so eager to 'improve' the experience they scroll and scale and reorient my carefully laid out ui, and break all kinds of things dependant on screen coords etc.

So how do I turn off all this noise? Unlike a public facing webpage, I have physical access literally all the devices I need to target so I know it /can/ be done. Is there a config file somewhere phone I can hack? Is there a specific browser I can install and tell to behave? Is this what phonegap if for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your code base native or is this all set up as a web tool?

Comment: it's all set up as a web tool atm, because that's what I personally can edit in real-time. If I have to slog through learning about android devices/configs,browsers that's fine as long as in the end, 'on stage', I can edit a .jade, hit refresh and have new UI widgets to mess with.

Comment: As long as its a webtool youll be at the mercy of the browser because different browsers listen too or ignore certain javascript or html commands. You could always wrap your webtool in an android app and run it all through a webview which runs natively on the device instead of hosting it on a server. Theres plenty of simple tutorials on how to do so and it shouldnt be to much of an undertaking if your already writing javascript and other stuff.